# Sum up data from joined table for specific columns (oracle 9i)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I have two tables:

replies_referred and advert_view_hits

**replies_referred** contains a lot of fields but the relevant ones are:

```
ad_id, acc_id and referrer
```

advert_view_hits contains (sb_id is the same as acc_id):

```
ad_id, date, hits, referrer, sb_id, F
```

advert_view hits is used to record views and hits to adverts and replies_referred is used to record replies to that adverts.

Normally i would use the following query to total up the number of adverts, views and clicks by referrer

```
select referrer, count(distinct ad_id) as Adverts,
            sum(case f when 'Y' then hits else 0 end) as clicks,
            sum(case f when 'N' then hits else 0 end) as views
            from advert_view_hits
            where ad_id in ('3325371', '3319035', '3318234')
            group by referrer;
```

Which produces results like:

```
 Referrer             Adverts  Clicks  Views
 Caterer               3       124     74
 Indeed                5       3       24
```

But there is a discrepancy between the two tables. Referrers exist in the advert_view_hits table that do not exist in the replies_referred table. So I want to use the referrer values form the replies_referred in the above query. Also want to use the adverts count from the replies_referred table.

But when i try to join both tables the results for the clicks and views are wrong and much higher than they should be.

```
select r.referrer, count(distinct r.ad_id) as Adverts,
            sum(case a.f when 'Y' then hits else 0 end) as clicks,
            sum(case a.f when 'N' then hits else 0 end) as views
            from replies_referred r
            join advert_view_hits a on a.ad_id = r.ad_id
            where r.ad_id in ('3325371', '3319035', '3318234')
            group by r.referrer;
```

Which produces results like:

```
Referrer             Adverts  Clicks  Views
Caterer               3       5473     49730
Indeed                5       234      111
```

I have tried using sub queries to get clicks and views but it results in ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression errors.

How do I join both tables and sum up the views and clicks correctly?

sample data from advert_view_hits:

[image]

Comment: Some sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: I added some sample data from the advert_view_hits table and desired results are just like I have shown in the question after the first query. Its when i do the join that views and clicks end up in thousands when they shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `join` conditions are wrong.  Perhaps you need to include the account as well:

```
select r.referrer, count(distinct r.ad_id) as Adverts,
        sum(case a.f when 'Y' then hits else 0 end) as clicks,
        sum(case a.f when 'N' then hits else 0 end) as views
from replies_referred r join
     advert_view_hits a 
     on a.ad_id = r.ad_id and a.acc_id = r.sb_id
where r.ad_id in ('3325371', '3319035', '3318234')
group by r.referrer;
```

Comment: that still results in massively overblown results from views and clicks. I think it must be summing up all the views and clicks rather than just the specifics ones for caterer for example

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to come up with this query which is closer to the results i am looking for but it is incredibly slow.

```
   select referrer,
   count(distinct ad_id) as adverts,
   sum(case f when 'Y' then hits else 0 end) as clicks,
   sum(case f when 'N' then hits else 0 end) as views
   from advert_view_hits
   where referrer IN (
        select DISTINCT r.referrer
        from replies_referred r
        where r.ad_id in ('3325371', '3319035', '3318234')
    )
   and ad_id IN ('3325371', '3319035', '3318234')
   group by referrer;
```